# Recursive regex pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex, recursion, recursive-regex

I'd like to use tag-style annotations in html text to replace sections of text/html depending on variable names using PHP. The replacement itself works perfectly if not using nested tags.
But if there are nested tags, only the outer one gets replaced.

My regex is this one:

```
\[\@if(not)?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:=(.*?))?\].*?\[\@endif:\2\]
```

You can see this regex in action with example content to parse here:
https://regex101.com/r/rE3fL1/2

I've read about `(?R)`  but can't get it to work.
I tried replacing the `.*?` in the middle with `(.*?|(?R))` but that doesn't even change anything.

**How do I change the regex to also capture nested Tags?**

Code: (`$this->output` accesses the Text)

```
public function output($dbAccess = true) {
        // only translate when dbaccess is granted
        if ($dbAccess) 
            $this->localize();

        // insert values into template
        foreach ( $this->values as $key => $value ) {
            $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
            $this->output = str_replace ( $tagToReplace, $value, $this->output );
        }

        // gather conditional content sections from output
        $condis = array();
        $conmatches = array ();
        preg_match_all ( '/\[\@if(not)?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:=(.*?))?\].*?\[\@endif:\2\]/s', $this->output, $conmatches );
        if (count($conmatches) > 0) {
            $c = $conmatches[0];
//          if (count($c) > 0)
//              echo "found " . count($c[0]) . " conditional tpl statement matches!";
            for ($i=0; $i<count($c); $i++) {
                $text = $c[$i];
                $not = $conmatches[1][$i];
                $name = $conmatches[2][$i];
                $value = $conmatches[3][$i];
                $condis[] = new ConditionalContent($text, $not, $name, $value);
            }

            // substitute conditional content sections
            foreach ($condis as $cc) {
                // convenience and readability vars!
                $varname = $cc->name();
                $vals = &$this->values;
                $value = $cc->value();

                // if condition is bound to value of variable and not just existence
                if ($value != "") {
                    // del if name == exists(value)
                    if ($cc->not() && isset($vals[$varname])) {
                        if ($vals[$varname] == $value) {
                            $this->delContent($cc->content());
                        }
                    }
                    // del if not exists(value) or value != name
                    else {
                        if (!isset($vals[$varname]) || $vals[$varname] != $value) {
                            $this->delContent($cc->content());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (    isset($vals[$varname]) && $cc->not() || 
                            !isset($vals[$varname]) && !$cc->not()) {
                        $this->delContent($cc->content());
                    }
                }
            }

            // delete all left over if(not) and endif statements
            $this->output = preg_replace('/\[@(?:if(?:not){0,1}|endif):[a-zA-Z0-9]+(=.*?)?\]/', '', $this->output);
        }
        //else { echo "found no conditional tpl statements"; }

        return $this->output;
    }
```

Comment: why not just use a php variable?

Comment: Because this part of a small template system that i use to separate logic from view.

Comment: I think this will not work; the content you're searching for matches `.*` because you're looking specifically for `\[\@endif:\2\]` after it. The recursion you need to do is in the PHP code, re-running `preg_match()` on each element of `$conmatched` to look for further subsections.

Comment: With the way you write the regex, you are looking for trouble. While PCRE can do bracket balancing, it will quickly become complex when you want to parse a full-blown tag markup. You might want to take a look at existing BBCode parser for inspiration.